# Mobile Website, Select box does not appear on Android

Tags: android, css, forms, mobile

I am building a Mobile website. The form on the website has a select box. The select box appears in iOS and Android, however when you select an item on an Android device, the text does not appear. (You can select an item but once selected, it doesn't appear in the box)

Has anybody else had the same issue, or know of a fix for this?

Many Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/hJwfd/

```
<select id="Question19" name="Question19">
    <option selected="selected" value="">----</option>
    <option>Google</option>
    <option>Yahoo</option>
    <option>MSN</option>
    <option>AlterVista</option>
    <option>Store</option>
    <option>Local Press</option>
    <option>National Press</option>
    <option>A Friend</option>
    <option>TV Advert</option>
    <option>Other</option>
 </select>

.formBlockSurveyTable select {
    padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000 !important;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Sure I can fix it, if you can show me some code.

Comment: I have tried the standard -webkit-appearance: none; but no luck with this

Comment: Please update the code in your question, not in the comment.
I have added in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJwfd/), seems to work fine. If you still have problem, recreate the issue and post the JSFiddle link in your question. Someone/me will help you.

Comment: Updated this in the question. Thanks